# pixel-scroll-precision-mode has no effect

Tags: scrolling, gui-emacs

I've just updated to Emacs 29, but running `(pixel-scroll-precision-mode 1)`, even with `emacs -Q`, doesn't have any visible effect for me. `(default-value 'pixel-scroll-precision-mode)` evaluates to `t` but scrolling is still instant.

I'm running 29.1 built with XInput 2 support (`system-configuration-options` pasted below) under X, and AFAIK there's nothing else that should be necessary for this to work. Any idea what gives?

I don't think it should be relevant, but I'm running i3 and I have Emacs installed through Nix.

`system-configuration-options`: `"--prefix=/nix/store/zbh69bbb8c13w5rrpbhp9rsa7aax4d42-emacs-29.1 --disable-build-details --with-modules --with-x-toolkit=lucid --with-xft --with-cairo --with-native-compilation --with-tree-sitter --with-xinput2"`

Comment: Is there anything unusual about your mouse/wheel hardware or config?

Comment: No, AFAIK... consistent behaviour for both mouse and trackpad, neither of which I remember ever needing any special configuration or behaving badly with other programs.

Comment: Same on macOS. Didn’t spend much time looking into it though. Might be something that changed since RC1 and release. Don’t know

Comment: If you think some user option "has no effect" then `M-x report-emacs-bug`, giving a recipe and specifying what you mean by "has no effect".

Comment: @Drew Sorry, I'm finding it hard to think of more explanation of "no effect". I can't see any difference in scrolling with `pixel-scroll-precision-mode` enabled or disabled, scrolling is instant either way. Anyway, I'm not confident that there is a bug here; I think it's more likely that I'm doing something silly that someone here might be able to point out. If that isn't the case, eventually I'll call it a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually was because of Nix - my Nix-installed Emacs wasn't linking my system libXi. It was easier for me to just stop using Nix to manage Emacs than to fix this, so I never found a real solution.

See [Po Lu's response on the mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2023-08/msg01975.html).

Answer (score 1):

oldosfan (a.k.a. Po Lu, the author of `pixel-scroll-precision-mode`) (quoted from [here](https://emacs-china.org/t/emacs/19016)):

> **如果滚轮不支持像素滚动，请不要报告 bug，这种滚轮我不会支持。**
>
> Translation: **If the scroll wheel does not support pixel scrolling, please do not report bugs, as this type of scroll wheel will not be supported.**

For users using macOS or MS-Windows, you can download [SmoothScroll](https://www.smoothscroll.net/) to simulate pixel scrolling.
I believe there is similar software for GNU/Linux as well.

---

OP has reported the question as [bug#65514](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=65514).

Comment: Here is a pixel scrolling demo (using SmoothScroll on MS-Windows): <https://github.com/shynur/.emacs.d/issues/1#issuecomment-1671844378>

Comment: I don't think my scroll wheel is the cause, because scrolling with the touchpad doesn't work either. Or am I misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: @wohanley: If you want to report a bug, report it. Or, before doing so, you can try some similar software I mentioned earlier.